# Annotation for retrying all methods in a class instead of using @Retryable for each method

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-retry

We use @Retryable annotation to retry specific methods in a class.

Is there any annotation to commonly retry all methods in a class.Instead of making it in method level, can we move to Class level.

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/annotation/Retryable.html), this annotation can _target_ [methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html?is-external=true#METHOD) and [types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html?is-external=true#TYPE). Did you try?

Answer (score -2):

Add this in configuration and then follow it http://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry

```
@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class AppConfig { ... }
```